# Git on Windows: Where are my files?

Tags: git, version-control, github

WARNING: I'M NEW TO GIT!!

I installed git on my local machine. I also installed it on a server on our network. On the server, I created `C:\git` to house my code and shared that directory. So, I did:

```
$cd C:\git
$git init --bare
```

I set up a new remote on my local machine to point to the shared directory of the "git server"

```
$git remote add shared "//shared/path/to/git/folder"
$cd C:\path\to\my\source\code
$git init
$git add -A
$git commit -m "initial push"
$git push shared master
$git checkout -b test
$git push shared test
```

So, now that I've done all that, when I go back to the server, I am expecting to see the server copies of my source code there, but I don't see it. Am I missing the entire point of git or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git stores your source as "binary large objects" (BLOBs, or just "objects" for short).  A bare repository, like the one on your server, contains ONLY those BLOBs, not a "working tree", which is what your cloned repository has, which is why you can't see your files as normal on the server.  They're there, uniquely named based on their content, in the `objects` directory.  Try this experiment:

```
git init

echo "hello" > hello.txt

git add hello.txt

dir .git/objects
```

You'll see a subdirectory called `2a`.  Look inside that directory:

```
dir .git/objects/2a
```

You'll see a file called `93d00994fbd8c484f38b0423b7c42e87a55d48`.  The directory name (`2a`) along with the filename make up the SHA1 hash of the *contents* of the file `hello.txt` (the string "hello", that is).

Now if you type:

```
git cat-file -p 2a93d00994fbd8c484f38b0423b7c42e87a55d48
```

You'll see the contents of `hello.txt`!  That's the object that'll be stored in the bare repository, which is why you don't just see the file `hello.txt` sitting there; it's been given a special name, compressed, and put in the `objects` directory.

As your repository grows, things get a little more complicated, because as the size of your content, and the number of your commits grow, Git starts packing similar files together; all of the information is still there, but it's further compressed for efficiency.

Another way you can reassure yourself that your files are indeed being stored on your server, you can create another clone (not a bare one!) and you'll have a working tree with all of your files in it.

Answer (score 4):

You intialized `bare` repository. It does not have source code structure. It does not contain a "working tree" at all. Instead, it contains all the contents of the .git subdirectory right in the main directory itself.

So if you want a working copy on your server you have to `clone` your code from bare repo. Then `pull` latest commits to syncronize it.

Comment: I think I understand, but at the same time - a little confused. If I the server is not hosting the files, then when I do a "pull" from different machine, where is the code "pulling" from?

Comment: Working copy on server should be cloned and pulled from bare repo. Think about it exactly as about repository, not working copy or your source code.

Comment: @jaressloo I see `github` tag here. So, github is a bare repo. You make your local code changes, commit them, then `push` to github repo. After this you `pull` this commits to your server working copy from github. That's all workflow. 8)

Comment: To clarify, the server essentially only stores the history, without actually holding a copy of the newest files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually commit your files!

```
$git add -A
$git commit -m "First commit"
```

Comment: Sorry, I did commit and push my code. I just forgot to mention that I commited the code.