# Does GIT always dependent on local repositories among collaborators

Tags: git, svn, github

Friends
We are in the process of migrating svn to GIT in a small organization. As I understood for team collaboration we need to do the following.
1) Create a bare repository in Server (repos.git folder won't have working copy means no source codes). It will record the push details .

2) create a local repo in developer 1's machine put source there then stage ,commit and push it by pointing to the bare repository url. Still no source will be available in my server machine.

3) Developer 2 will clone this bare repository and pull the source code.. The devloper 2 will get the source file from developer 1's machine right ?not from server ? since server contains only a bare repo. what if the developer 1's machine is offline? DOES  GIT always dependent on local repositories among collaborator's machines?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Yes.  3) No.  *FUNDAMENTAL DIFFERENCE*: SVN is a "VCS" (Version Control System).  Git is a "DVCS" (*DISTRIBUTED* Version Control System).  Here's why that's an important distinction: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/why-you-should-switch-from-subversion-to-git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's never direct communication between developer 1 and developer 2's machines.  The server/client model is similar to other version control systems: each developer talks to the server separately.
After stage 2, the source should be on the server, because developer 1 pushed it there. So when developer 2 pulls the repository, he should get the source.

Comment: Thanks John ... Infact i got answer from another thread and I am going to test that . the info is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358451/git-on-windows-where-are-my-files.

Comment: Well, there _can be_ direct communication between developer 1 and developer 2's machines. But this isn't automatic. Nothing is stopping two developers from sharing commits directly, bypassing the "server" entirely (though there may be some setup required for this).

Comment: @Navas Abdul Karim: two important points: 1) Git is a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control).  So - unlike SVN - you don't need to be connected to "the server" to view history, update source, etc. etc.  2) The files under the .git folder are all ["objects"](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects).  They comprise the "git database".  You must use commands like git clone to access the underlying source files.